# vBulletin check if current page usercp.php?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, vbulletin

How i can do something like this in vBulletin script ?

check if current page `usercp.php`

Comment: Can you please add some code samples or explain your question with more details?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.


I found the solution , i need if statement to show something if current page for example **usercp.php**

`<if condition="THIS_SCRIPT == 'index' OR THIS_SCRIPT == 'forumdisplay' OR THIS_SCRIPT == 'showthread'"> show your ad </if>`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

If the current page is usercp will display text.

```
<if condition="THIS_SCRIPT == 'usercp'"> Text </if>
```

Or u can check more than one page

```
<if condition="THIS_SCRIPT == 'index' OR THIS_SCRIPT == 'forumdisplay' OR THIS_SCRIPT == 'showthread'">
 Text
</if>
```